Question about a result from learning theory dealing with "how close is the empirical risk to the real risk"?
I am reading an optimization paper on machine learning where a result from learning theory is stated. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a model class, $$R(h) = \int L(h(x),y)\;dP(x,y)$$ the general risk and $$R_n(h) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n L(h(x_i),y_i)$$ empirical risk. Let $d_{\mathcal{H}}$ be the VC dimension of $\mathcal{H}$. According to the paper we then have with probability $1-\rho$
$$\sup_{h\in \mathcal{H}}|R(h)-R_n(h)| \in \mathcal{O}\Biggl(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2n}log\Bigl(\frac{2}{\rho}\Bigr)+\frac{d_{\mathcal{H}}}{n}log\Bigl(\frac{n}{d_{\mathcal{H}}} \Bigr)}\Biggr)$$
How does this right-hand side makes sense with $d_{\mathcal{H}} >> n$ ?
I mean isn't the part inside of the root negative if $d_{\mathcal{H}}$ is a lot bigger than $n$?

I think there is an implicit assumption in such results that $d_{\mathcal{H}} \leq n$, because results with a $O\left(\sqrt{\frac{\log(n/d_{\mathcal{H}})}{n/d_{\mathcal{H}}}}\right)$ type term are generally proven using Sauer's Lemma. In the case where $d_{\mathcal{H}} > n$, we get a vacuous bound.
For more context, recall the definition of VC dimension of $\mathcal{H}$ as the largest set size shattered by $\mathcal{H}$. The VC dimension is often defined in terms of the growth function of the hypothesis class $\Pi_{\mathcal{H}}$ (maximum # of ways that hypotheses in $\mathcal{H}$ can classify $n$ points in a two-class setting):
$$\operatorname{VC}(\mathcal{H}) \triangleq \max \: \{n \mid \Pi_{\mathcal{H}}(n) = 2^n\}.$$
A standard growth-bound based generalization bound (left as an exercise; e.g., Eq. 3.23 of Mohri's Foundations of Machine Learning) is:
$$\underset{h \in \mathcal{H}}{\sup} \; |R(h) - R_n(h)| \leq \sqrt{\frac{8\log \Pi_{\mathcal{H}}(2n) + 8 \log(4/\delta)}{n}}.$$
As a reminder, these results define $R(h)$ and $R_n(h)$ as the population and empirical 0-1 error, such that $R(h), R_n(h) \leq 1$. This will become relevant later.
To turn this into a VC-dimension based bound, Sauer's Lemma is then applied, which states that, if $n \geq d_{\mathcal{H}}$, then $\Pi_{\mathcal{H}}(n) \leq \sum_{i=0}^{d_{\mathcal{H}}} \binom{n}{i} \leq \left(\frac{em}{d_{\mathcal{H}}}\right)^{d_{\mathcal{H}}}$. Substituting this bound and some algebra yields
$$\underset{h \in \mathcal{H}}{\sup} \; |R(h) - R_n(h)| \leq \sqrt{\frac{8d_{\mathcal{H}}\log \frac{2en}{d_{\mathcal{H}}} + 8 \log(4/\delta)}{n}}.$$
Note that this differs from your bound only by constant factors.
However, if $n < d_{\mathcal{H}}$, then $\Pi_{\mathcal{H}}(n) = 2^n$ by definition (all possible sets of binary predictions on a set of size $n$ are realizable). After some algebra, we get the bound
$$\underset{h \in \mathcal{H}}{\sup} \; |R(h) - R_n(h)| \leq \sqrt{\frac{16n\log 2 + 8 \log(4/\delta)}{n}},$$
which is vacuous, since we could write
$$\underset{h \in \mathcal{H}}{\sup} \; |R(h) - R_n(h)| \leq 4 \sqrt{\log 2 } \approx 3.33 \leq \sqrt{\frac{16n\log 2 + 8 \log(4/\delta)}{n}}.$$
But, by definition, we know that $\underset{h \in \mathcal{H}}{\sup} \; |R(h) - R_n(h)| \leq 1$, so any bound looser than that for any choice of $n, \delta$ isn't very useful.
